# Combining two queries by JOINing several tables

Tags: join

I have a dtabase of players with around 20 tables.
I am trying to figure out the debut (first match appearance) of a specific player. The database have two seperate tables for 'appearances' and 'substitutions'. Initially I managed to get my query right seperately, that is to say I managed to get the details of the first appearence in one query  and  get the details of the substitution on another query. I have tried several procedures to combune bothe queries into one, but eveytime I tried , some errors occured. Yes, and I have done a lot of googling as well.
Here are the seperate procedures:

## to Display a player's full debut details.

```
SELECT DATE( MatchDateTime ) , tplss_opponents.OpponentName, CONCAT(MatchGoals,"-", MatchGoalsOpponent), PlayerLastName
FROM tplss_matches
JOIN tplss_opponents ON tplss_matches.MatchOpponent = tplss_opponents.opponentID
JOIN tplss_appearances ON tplss_matches.MatchID = tplss_appearances.AppearanceMatchID 
JOIN tplss_players ON tplss_appearances.AppearancePlayerID=  tplss_players.PlayerID
WHERE `PlayerLastName` = "Leo Messi"
ORDER BY `MatchDateTime` ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

## Display a player debut details includes substitution.

```
SELECT DATE( MatchDateTime ) , tplss_opponents.OpponentName, CONCAT(MatchGoals,"-", MatchGoalsOpponent), PlayerLastName
FROM tplss_matches
JOIN tplss_opponents ON tplss_matches.MatchOpponent = tplss_opponents.opponentID
JOIN tplss_substitutions ON tplss_matches.MatchID = tplss_substitutions.SubstitutionMatchID
JOIN tplss_players ON tplss_substitutions.SubstitutionPlayerIDIn=  tplss_players.PlayerID
WHERE `PlayerLastName` = "Leo Messi"
ORDER BY `MatchDateTime` ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

My objective to to find the first record of a player playing in a match , either as a starter or as a substitute from the bench, whichever is earlier. This is commonly called "Debut".

A sample of the query output:

DATE        OpponentName    result  PlayerLastName
2005-08-17  Hungary     2-1     Lionel MESSI

Appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: What's wrong with two separate, simpler queries and taking the min between the two?

Comment: Nothing wrong with 2 seperate queries, and that is what I am doing right now. I thought it is more appropriate to have a single one and far shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with 'union all' and subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM (
-- Select from Debut --
UNION ALL
-- Select from substitution --
) AS tmp
ORDER BY MatchDateTime ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponce. I am getting  #1064 - you have an error an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `PlayerLastName` = "nekounam" UNION ALL SELECT DATE( MatchDateTime )' at line 6 ........... I have tried the UNION before, but I must admit. I am confused about getting the right syntax. Still scratching my head and trying.

Comment: OK...I eventually got the parenthesis right, but I am still getting two results (two rows) from the UNION query. I need just the one with the older date.

Comment: Can you post your new query?

Comment: If you use only the UNION ALL every query returns their values, instead you have to use the union all as a subquery and limit the subquery.
I try to create a better example:
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT date AS MatchDateTime FROM debut WHERE mycolumn = 'Value'
UNION ALL
SELECT other_date AS MatchDateTime FROM substitution WHERE mycolumn2 = 'Value'
) AS tmp
ORDER BY MatchDateTime
LIMIT 1. 

tmp is the results of the subquery and you can use as a normal table.

Comment: I have revised the code several times, and eventually found out that when using UNION in the query , it should have a unique ORDER by clause, so my amended query looks like this:

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post the whole revised code, it says "too much characters:..Hmmm... Anyway , I used the date clause on both queries and named them as union_sort and then ORDER BY union_sort at the end of the second query. That did the trick. Than you all.